# Error: the global scope has no GetUrl

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, dll, dllexport

I have a new problem with my C++ DLL... I have tried exporting the entire class instead of only one method. But the program doesn't want to compile now because of that the global scope has no GetUrl

Here is my "UrlConnector.h":

`#define ConnectMe __declspec( dllexport )`

namespace ConnectHttps
{
 class ConnectMe
 {
  void GetUrl(char *url, unsigned int bufferLength);
 };
}


and here is the part of my UrlConnector.cpp that isn't compiling:

`#include "UrlConnector.h"
#include "MyConnectionClass.h"
#include 
using namespace std;`

namespace ConnectHttps
{
 void ConnectMe::GetUrl(char* url, unsigned bufferLength)
 {
  MyConnectionClass initSec;
  string response = initSec.GetResult();
  strncpy_s(url, bufferLength, response.c_str(), response.length());
 }
}

Now, I would like to be able to create an DLL from this, and I would like to make a test program to call the class and the method GetUrl from a dll. I'm using Visual Studio 2010 with Visual C++ DLL.
 
I've also managed to read [this from the MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/81h27t8c%28VS.80%29.aspx) and [this tutorial](http://www.dotnetheaven.com/Uploadfile/mahesh/DLLBasicsPart105192005020909AM/DLLBasicsPart1.aspx?ArticleID=0761024a-f5f8-43f1-9e7a-e1da67a862e1) as well, but I just can't seem to get it to work!
I would really appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I'm mistaken, you don't seem to be giving your class a name. 
You made ConnectMe not a class name but a macro to export your class, but your class should have a name

Maybe try

```
#define EXPORT_IT __declspec( dllexport )

namespace ConnectHttps
{
    class EXPORT_IT ConnectMe
    {
        void GetUrl(char *url, unsigned int bufferLength);
    };
}
```

Also I'm not 100% sure of this because I don't have access to a compiler at the moment, but typing:

```
namespace ConnectHttps {
    ...
}
```

In your .cpp file isn't correct. Instead you should have:

```
void ConnectHttps::ConnectMe::GetUrl(char* url, unsigned bufferLength)
{
    MyConnectionClass initSec;
    string response = initSec.GetResult();
    strncpy_s(url, bufferLength, response.c_str(), response.length());
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer... you are #1